# Primary keys in Room should be Int or Long?

Tags: android, database, kotlin

I'm designing a Database that would be implemented in Android using Room, after reading the docs I found that there is no recomendations about using Int or Long as primary keys.

In some places they define entities with int primary keys:

```
@Entity
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey var id: Int,
    var firstName: String?,
    var lastName: String?
)
```

But in other place it says that if you want to get the ID of the last row inserted "insert" method return a long.

```
@Dao
interface MyDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertUsers(vararg users: User)

    @Insert
    fun insertBothUsers(user1: User, user2: User)

    @Insert
    fun insertUsersAndFriends(user: User, friends: List<User>)
}
```

> If the @Insert method receives only 1 parameter, it can return a long, which is the new rowId for the inserted item. If the parameter is an array or a collection, it should return long[] or List instead.

So, The primary keys in room should be Int or Long?; Are there best practices about choosing one type over the other?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Both of these types will map to an `INTEGER` in the underlying SQLite database.

For example, with a class like this:

```
@Entity
data class Test(@PrimaryKey val i: Int, val l: Long)
```

You'd get a SQLite table defined with this query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Test` (`i` INTEGER NOT NULL, `l` INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`i`))
```

So you can use whichever one you'll need the magnitude of in your code. If you do decide to use an `Int` for some reason and you run out of values, you can even change it to a `Long` without having to migrate your database later on.

As for this `INTEGER` type, as per the [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

Comment: Does it mean that integer in SQLite uses a variable-length encoding?

Answer (score 12):

Both is fine. On mobile (and most of the time in general)  `Int` should be sufficient (it will also save you 4 bytes over `Long`).

**Why?** Using an `Int` you could store over 2 billion records (2_000_000_000). So you could store a record of around `1/4` of all the humans living on earth. Just for comparison: Using a `Long` would enable you to store over 900 quadrillion records (900_000_000_000_000_000).

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to use Long since the insert function will return a Long, or long[].

Comment: this is actually a good point